# WPF combobox set selected item on lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, updatesourcetrigger

I have:

```
<Combobox ItemsSouce="{Binding SomeCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeItem}" />
```

My property `SomeItem` looks like:

```
public object SomeItem 
{
    get
    {
       return _someItem;
    }
    set
    {
        LogMessage("SomeItem has changed to" + value);
        _someItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SomeItem");
    }
}
```

How can I prevent calling the set method when the user scrolls through the combobox? I want to call that set method when the combobox loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the updatesource trigger lost focus in the binding.

```
<Combobox ItemsSouce="{Binding SomeCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Comment: It still calls the set method :(